# Why does the website url is appending when I call an proxy server api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, redux, axios

I am working on a react application . I configured proxy using module http-proxy-middleware.

At flags page , website url looks like `//localhost:9000/flags/all` .

When user clicks on a button in flags page , I need to call sparkle(rest service) api  and should load the result. When I call the sparkle api , internally website url is also appending and the api call is forming like `http://SGD01D:10700/all/sparkle/flags` instead of `//SGD01D:10700/sparkle/flags` . Why "all" is appending to the api call? How to solve this issue

```
//server
app.use('/sparkle', proxy(proxies.sparkle_config()));

 //Proxy config
class proxies {
  static sparkle_config() {
    return {
      target: 'http://SGD01D:10700', // target host
      changeOrigin: true // needed for virtual hosted sites
    };
  }
}

export default proxies;


//React action
//redux-thunk
export function loadFlags() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(beginAjaxCall());

    const promise = axios({url: 'sparkle/v1/api/flag', timeout: 20000, method: 'get', responseType: 'json'});

    promise.then(function(flags) {              
      dispatch(loadFlagsSuccess(flags));
    }).catch(function(error) {
      throw(error);
    });

  };
}
```

Comment: On flags page `//localhost:9000/flags/all`, the Ajax request to `sparkle/v1/api/flag` will result in request to `//localhost:9000/flags/sparkle/v1/api/flag`, which will not hit `app.use('/sparkle',...)`. Can you open browser DevTool to confirm?

Comment: Also, the request to `sparkle/v1/api/flag` would be proxied to something like `.../v1/api/flag`. It's unlikely to be proxied to `sparkle/flags`. Is there something missing in your code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My Observations are below , please check once.                 Website URL = http://localhost:9000/flag/all,

    API called = 'sparkle/v1/api/flag',

Developer tools url = http://localhost:9000/flag/sparkle/v1/api/flag  (results in 404),


Should be = http://localhost:9000/sparkle/v1/api/flag,


One more observation:

If my website url is like  http://localhost:9000/flag/all/testing,
then Dev tools url  =  http://localhost:9000/flag/sparkle/all/v1/api/flag  (results in 404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem because relative paths in your API call. I would call the API with Axios with an absolute path:

```
const promise = axios({url: '/sparkle/v1/api/flag', timeout: 20000, method: 'get', responseType: 'json'});
```